# Merging Solutions - From Different Source Control

Tags: svn, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn, azure-devops

I'm having a few problems. It's hard to really explain what that problem is without going into the background history.

We work with a development partner who issues us periodically with a Development Pack, which is a Visual Studio solution of many projects representing some 30,000 source files. They issue us a Subversion repo where we go and download the DevPacks as they release them.

We started off with this "DevPack" and have been working with it in our team for many months. We have added our own source files and modified some core code. We use Visual Studio Team Services to manage our source control in our team.

Now, our partner has given us a new DevPack. So I have a new (read only) subversion repo to download the new code from.

I have been trying for the past few days to download and merge the new DevPack into our live code.

I believe we should be able to use TortoiseSVN to checkout the code from the repo into my TFS working directory. Tortoise should then highlight new and changed files and give me merge options too. But it doesn't work. It simply comes up saying that files already exist and are "versioned".

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your choice of source control I would do the following:

**Initial setup with the first DevPack**

1. Commit the received DevPack to a folder, let's call it *Partner* branch, without doing any changes.
2. Make a branch of *Partner*, let's call it *Dev*, for doing you own changes.

**When you receive a new DevPack**

1. Check-out the entire *Partner* branch and copy the new DevPack to the local folder.
2. Compare server vs. local to discover removed/added files and remove/add these accordingly.
3. Commit changes to the *Partner* branch.
4. Merge from *Partner* to the *Dev* and commit when satisfied.

Using the above approach, you can both see what changes your partner does to his delivery and be able to merge their changes into your modified version.

Comment: I've been trying that today.

Comment: I've been trying that today - It's able to get the missing source files but it's not updating the project.

I've switched to looking at this on a per file basis. See if I can fix it in a single file and apply the same logic to the rest of the solution.

The .CSPROJ file in SVN, if I download a fresh copy, lists the files correctly. 

If I try and do any sort of merge/update on that specific file my working copy simply never updates - it always retains the original file.

Comment: I have tried to improve the proposed solution so it should be easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks - It is easier to understand. However the situation I am in is that we already have a "branch" of code which is using the old DevPack, so there is no Tree/Branch relationship between the two. What I tried to do instead was upload the latest devpack and make that a branch (Partner). Then, I created a new branch (Dev) from that to make the relationship so it was essentially a duplicate copy. I then checked out the Dev branch, and copied my Solution into that branch, overwriting the files and checked them all in. However when I try and "merge" Dev into partner it says there are no changes.

Comment: I would rather merge from *Partner* to *Dev*, but it is still vierd that it claims that there are no changes. What happens if you compare the two branches?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to these steps to achieve that:

1. Upload latest devpack to source control and make that a branch (Partner)
2. Create a new branch (Dev) from Partner branch
3. Check in changes of Dev branch
4. Copy your solution into Dev branch (local mapping folder)
5. **Check in changes (changes in step 4) of Dev branch** (Otherwise you will get there are no changes result)
6. Merge Dev branch to Partner branch and deal with conflict